# Unable to list of staff who handles the most appointments in a particular month and year

Tags: sql

I am trying to list the staff who handles the most/least appointments in a particular month and year but due to some reason it's not working. Please can anyone help me to solve.

[image: Staff Table]

[image: Appointment Table]

I tried something like below but it's not working:

```
SELECT COUNT (a.staff_id) AS appointments_count,
       appointment_date,
       b.staff_name
FROM appointment a, staff b
WHERE a.staff_id = b.staff_id
GROUP BY staff_name
ORDER BY appointments_count DESC
```

Comment: provide your desired output in table format

Comment: What have you tried and did not work?

Comment: @Fahmi I have edited my question ...you can check it now

Comment: @GMB  I have mentioned above in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT b.staff_name,COUNT(a.staff_id) AS appointments_count
FROM appointment a join staff b on a.staff_id = b.staff_id
where appointment_date>='20200801' and appointment_date<='20200830'
GROUP BY b.staff_name 
ORDER BY appointments_count DESC
```

Comment: @Sansui, what is the error or what is the resultset this query returns?

Comment: Error Code : 1305
FUNCTION propertyrental.COUNT does not exist

Comment: @Sansui, which dbms you are using? Though I've edited the code, you can give  try